# Practical scenarios related to passing an Object of type java.lang.Class<T> to a method

Tags: java, object

I confess to the curiosity of knowing any practical cases wherein it's required to pass a java.lang.Class's Object type or simply any *.class name to a method in java and waht could be the possible use of such an object:

as demonstrated by the code below, though below is a constructor but I would like to know if there are any general usage related to this:

```
public CustomerFacadeREST() {
        super(Customer.class);
    }
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Though question not very clear, what I understand is, you are asking what is the use of class object of any class. Well, you can use class object for reflective purposes i.e. to write logic that uses data you get via reflection...

Comment: Such questions are hard to answer because there is no general use case for something like that. Basically you'll know it when you need it ;-)

Comment: I mean wouldn't passing the object of class Customer above be another way of saying the same thing if not exactly the same?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is reflection, and why is it useful?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very useful in conjunction with generic methods: because of type erasure, generic methods cannot use their generic type parameter `T` in constructs such as `T.class`. Sometimes, this may be necessary - for example, to make new instances of class `T`.

Since `java.lang.Class<T>` is generic on the type itself (for `Customer`, that would be `java.lang.Class<Customer>`), and because the `Class` object can serve as a statically typed object factory (i.e. its `newInstance` method is generic, returning `T`) you can perform type-safe instantiation checked for you at compile time.

See [*Class Literals as Runtime-Type Tokens*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/literals.html) for more information on this technique.

Comment: +1.  This has been the most common use case in my own experience.  And even in cases where the type argument on `Class<T>` is not strictly required by the target method, its presence aids in type inference, and often eliminates the need for an explicit type argument at the call site.

Comment: As an example use case, I have a class which caches empty arrays of arbitrary types to avoid allocating a bunch of empty arrays throughout our system: `EmptyArrayCache.<T>fromElementType(Class<T> elementType)` returning `T[]`.  The `elementType` parameter tells the method what kind of empty array to return.

Comment: Thanks mike, more on the lines of what I wanted to know!

Answer (score 1):

You can use with DAO Design Pattern

```
class BaseDAO{
    Class class1;
    public BaseDAO(Class class1) {
        this.class1 =class1;
    }

    public Class getClass1() {
          return class1;
    }

     public void setClass1(Class class1) {
          this.class1 = class1;
    }

    public Object findById(long id){

    }

}
class CustomerFacadeREST extends BaseDAO{

     public CustomerFacadeREST() {
         super(Customer.class);
    }

}
```

Comment: Interesting, but is it just for the sake of design pattern or there is no other way than to pass Customer.class in super?

Comment: There are other ways (e.g., an abstract method `getUnderlyingType()` that the concrete DAO class overrides), but for this particular pattern, it may be useful to (a) have the underlying class available during initialization; and (b) be able to guarantee that it never changes.  This makes a constructor argument the natural choice.